# Why can't send form-data in postman

Tags: json, typescript, express, postman, middleware

Trying to send form-data in postman and sequelize return error:
`value cannot be null`

But when send raw request with json all ok. Trying body-parser and multer, but nothing working

This is my index.ts

```
import express from "express";
import fileUpload from "express-fileupload"
...


const app = express()
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5100

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())
app.use('/api', router)
app.use(fileUpload({}))
app.use(errorHandler)

const start = async () => {
    try {
        await sequelize.authenticate()
        await sequelize.sync()
        console.log(chalk.cyanBright('Successful conection to data base'));
        app.listen(PORT, () => { console.log(chalk.cyanBright(`Server has been started on port ${PORT}`)) })

    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}

start()
```

And this is my controller

```
export const DeviceController = {
    async create(req: Request, res: Response, next:nextType) {
        try {
            const { brandId, typeId, name, price } = req.body
            const img = req.files
            let filename = 'uuid.v4()' + '.jpg'
            img?.mv(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'static', filename))
            const device = await Models.Device.create({ brandId, typeId, name, price, img: filename })
            return res.json(device)
        } catch (error: any) {
            next(ApiError.badRequest(error.message))
            console.log(error);
            
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> app.use(express.json())
> ```

You have body parsing middleware for JSON request bodies.

You don't have body parsing middleware for multipart/form-data request bodies. The [documentation for body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) lists a several middlewares you could use.

> Trying body-parser

… which says it doesn't support that format

> and multart

… that doesn't appear to exist. Do you mean multiparty? Or maybe multer?

We can't tell you what you did wrong without seeing your attempt.

---

Re edit:

You said:

> ```
> const img = req.files
> img?.mv(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'static', filename))
> ```

But the documentation says:

> ```
> console.log(req.files.foo); // the uploaded file object
> ```

The `files` property contains all the files, indexed by the the names given to them in the multipart request.

You're trying to read that *collection* of files as if it were a single file.

Comment: Yes, I tried to use multer. Now trying to resolve this problem using express-fileupload

Comment: @AaaaaaaaaAaaaaaaaa — See edit to answer.

Comment: Ok. This is my very stupid mistake. I should use fileUpload middleware earlier than routes. Thank you